# Magento size units for product size

Tags: magento, size, product

Is there any work around or any module to show size for a product interchangeably in Inches and Centimeters.
For example: I have a box of size "H200 W50 D50" in inches, and Same size I also want to switch to Centimeter mode on fron-end to show size in Centimeters like "H450 W120 D120".

I don't want to show both at the same time, there will be option to switch between both.
I want them to be used dynamically, so for some products it will be Inches & Centimeters, for other it may be Kilograms and Pounds etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement such logic as:

Product has 3 attributes

```
MeasureA
MeasureB
MeasureType
```

On frontend there is some javascript which gets measuretype, and transforms from A to B.
Something like that.

Comment: Well, I also thought of it, but I can't do configurable products properly for size then. If I include both MeasureA and MeasureB as to use for configurable products, then it becomes MeasureA*MeasureB variations of product, which are not in reality.

Comment: Uhm ok. Then this is predefined attribute, and it has some code - right. For example length_inches and length_cent. Therefore you could check if this attribute is inches or cent origin.

Comment: Thanks JakeTheFish, but in my situation I can't manage two sizes for layered Navigation and few other things. I think I will use them both in one field for example 11Inches|25CM Now the | this is the seperator, I will do some logic to hide and show inches/CM from JS on front end. This way Size will remain 1.